# Creating a Student object for unit test

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, junit, objectmapper

I'm new to Java and needed some help. I have a utility class that has two methods where one method converts Json string to object and the other converts an object to Json string

I wanted to test these methods with junit. For this test purpose I would need an object ofcourse. Lets say a student object with a name and StudentId.

My question is that is there any way I can get this object in my Test without actually creating a separate class for the student? Since I only need this object for testing purposes.

Comment: Why would you need a separate class?

Comment: 1) "string to object" test: Assemble a valid JSON string, pass it to your method, then _assert that_ the returned object (a student) has the properties you expect. 2) "object to string" test: Create an instance of your student class, pass that to your method, then assert that the returned string is a valid JSON string representing your student.

Comment: @shmosel I just need any object for the test. Based on what I know, wouldn't the object need to have a class? In this case a Student class?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I don't have any student class. I just need a test object. So should i create a student class for the test?

Comment: So you're testing that serialization works for any type of object? You can't create an object without a class. You can use an anonymous subclass to reduce clutter, but that won't work for deserialization. I would say just create a static nested class, or even a local class if it's restricted to a single method.

Comment: Well ... tell us the methods' signatures.

Comment: I agree, your requirements are simply ... strange. The answers you got so far make all sense; to a certain degree; but with your unclear input, they are just blind shots. Maybe right; maybe not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Why create another Student class?
Just create a Student object in your junit test class (tests have to be separate from code of course)
It will be something like this:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.After;

public class StudentTest
{

    private Student tester;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        //init student objects
    }

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        //test logic
    }

    @After
    public void cleanUp()
    {
        //destruct
    }
}
```

see the junit documentation for an explanation of test logic, e.g. AssertNotNull
If your class isn't called student, take the class you ment on your question (your utility class?)

Comment: oh and, unlike the other comments, you don't explictly need to create a class. You can take your utility class for the test and simulate the outputs by feeding the methods with a stream.
It just isn't very clean because of potential code duplicates. You basically create new objects, give them teir input, eg the JSON, test and destruct

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a separate class, you could just create a static member class in your JUnit test class as shown in the example below:

```
public class StaticMemberClassDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student student = new Student("John Doe", 1);
    }

    private static class Student {
        private final String name;
        private final int id;

        public Student(String name, int id) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by a separate class here. Just note that in java you can define different types of [nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). Here it would not hurt to define a static nested class as rohitvats suggested.